# rvm install 2.7.2 Error running '__rvm_make -j16',

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

when i try install ruby 2.7.2 with command

`rvm install 2.7.2 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1`

it occures  error like:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j16',
please read /Users/bytedance/.rvm/log/1708932950_ruby-2.7.2/make.log
```

the make.log's useful info is:

```
command(2): __rvm_make -j16
++ make -j16
    BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN -I. -I.ext/include/arm64-darwin23 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
    CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/bytedance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib -compatibility_version 2.7 -current_version 2.7.2  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation
```

The Environment is:

Apple M3 Max

macOS 14.2.1

Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 0):

I've found that OpenSSL breaks when building Ruby after some macOS updates.

Make sure XCode is setup correctly:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Reinstall OpenSSL:

```
brew reinstall openssl@1.1
```

Try to install ruby again:

```
rvm get stable
rvm install 2.7.2 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`
```

Comment: Thanks.
After reinstall openssl@1.1, i set `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"` before `rvm install 2.7.2 `
it works.